# Binding Table data in Go Fyne

Tags: go, user-interface, fyne

Fyne beginner here.

There is simple use case I'm trying to solve, without finding any solution in the docs: in Fyne, **how to have a Table widget, with its data bound to a data source?**

In other words, we have the `binding.BindStringList` [in the docs](https://developer.fyne.io/tour/binding/list), that allows to bind a list of strings…

```golang
data := binding.BindStringList(
    &[]string{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"},
)
```

…I am looking for something similar that would allow to **bind a list of structs** instead of string. For example, a table of todos:

```golang
type Todo struct {
  UserID    int    `json:"userId,omitempty"`
  ID        int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
  Title     string `json:"title,omitempty"`
  Completed bool   `json:"completed,omitempty"`
}
```

If it is not possible, what would seem like the best workaround for you?

---

Well, following Andy's suggestion, I tried this:

```
var data []Todo

stringData := `[{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem"},{"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"quis ut nam facilis et officia qui"}]`
json.Unmarshal([]byte(stringData), &data)

var bindings []binding.DataMap

for _, todo := range data {
  bindings = append(bindings, binding.BindStruct(&todo))
}

list := widget.NewTable(
  func() (int, int) {
    return len(bindings), 4
  },
  func() fyne.CanvasObject {
    return widget.NewLabel("wide content")
  },
  func(i widget.TableCellID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
    title, _ := bindings[i.Row].GetItem("Title")
    log.Println(title)
    o.(*widget.Label).SetText(title)
  }
)
```

I don't manage to access the actual values of my elements (i.e. Title). Could you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not currently a data bound `Table` widget.
In v2.1 we plan to add `binding.BindMapList` which would be passed to `NewTableWithData`. In the upcoming release.

Until then you can maintain a slice of `binding.DataMap` items and access the items in it to bind the individual items inside the Table update callback methods.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Andy, this new feature in v2.1 sounds really exciting. Gonna try the workaround until then ;)

Comment: I tried to use `binding.DataMap`, but with no success. I'm missing something, but can't fix my code. I updated my initial post: could you please have a look?

Comment: Your code is really close to working I think, it's just the update callback.
You would use the result of `GetItem` to bind the label, like this:
```
  func(i widget.TableCellID, o fyne.CanvasObject) {
    title, _ := bindings[i.Row].GetItem("Title")
    o.(*widget.Label).Bind(title)
  }
```

Comment: Argh! I tried your code but it still complains with a `cannot use title (type binding.DataItem) as type binding.String in argument to o.(*"fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget".Label).Bind:
  binding.DataItem does not implement binding.String (missing Get method)` :(

Comment: Apologies, you need to cast the DataItem and I forgot. Try `Bind(title.(binding.String))` because the bindings are typed, but the contents of a DataMap are untyped.

Comment: Is v2.1 coming?

Comment: We are already at v2.2.3 and will release v2.3.0 next month

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Go Lang, see the import v2, but in go.mod figures the actual version, v2.2.3. 
I miss understand because I have not the NewTableWithData mentioned

Comment: Apologies, this is all not yet releases, we still have to add basic binding to Table and Tree… It would be great to get it in the v2.3.0 that is coming soon, but we have a lot of other priorities too…

Comment: I need to change no only data, I need to change the columns and rows size, with data binding is not enough. There is a way to achieve this?

Comment: Data binding is designed for just the data aspect. We don’t have any connections to have the UI layout respond automatically in that way. Outside of a scroll view it may update because you could have packed the widgets to show min size…

Comment: You would need to use manual data handling to do this with table.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation and tried your solution in a list.  All of my list items were displaying the text of the last item.  I modified the `range` loop as follows and I now get expected results

```
for i, _ := range data {
  bindings = append(bindings, binding.BindStruct(&data[i]))
}
```

My use case is a bit different than yours, but hopefully this will convey the concept.